# Showing And Playing My Audio Files From Path In List Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I succeeded in loading audio files from path and display it on a list activity,but what I want to do now is that after the file is displayed in a list activity, I want to be able to click any of the audio file and play it .

```
        myList = new ArrayList<String>();
        path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        file = new File(path + "/Download");

        File list[] = file.listFiles();

        for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
        {
            myList.add( list[i].getName() );
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myList);
        listv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
          final MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer();  
          mp.setDataSource(here is your audio file path);  
          mp.prepare();  
          //for audio start
          mp.start();  
         //for audio stop
         mp.stop();
        //for audio pause
         mp.pause();
```